# Raster to Polygon tool results in reduced area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, polygon-creation, raster-conversion

I have a large raster dataset within a file geodatabase (FGDBR format raster) which I have converted to polygon using the 'Raster to Polygon' tool.

Cell size of original raster = 25m.

Cell size of polygon = 25m.

Total area of original raster = 10,423,764 ha.

Total Area of polygon dataset = 10,235,534 ha.

Total area of raster when values extracted then added together (see 5th paragraph)                    = 10,235,534 ha.

Projected coordinate system = British National Grid

The area of the resulting polygon dataset is 1.8% less than area the cells of the original raster. However, visually; there is no difference between the two datasets (checked by overlaying them in ArcMap), except when 'zoomed' right out, then you can see slithers of the original raster cells outside the polygons. When scale is less than 1:200,000, the slithers disappear.

I calculated the original raster area by multiplying the cell count by the area of each square. I did not check the 'Simplify Polygons' option when using the tool.

I've also created the polygon dataset in different ways, such as using the 'Extract by Attributes' tool to extract separate parts of the raster and converting each part to polygon. But this also results in an area of 1.8% less, but no visual difference except at 1:200,000 scale or more.

I've also used Raster Calculator to subtract the extracted parts of the raster from the original raster, but this results on a raster with a value of 0 throughout.

Can anyone explain what is going on here please?

Comment: you should add more details about your original raster dataset. what cell sizes are you using? what's the total area covered by your raster? what coordinate system are you using?

Comment: I have added these now

Comment: Snap raster and extent are to be equal to source.

Comment: Hi @FelixIP can you expand on that please. How do I do this?

Comment: Go to environment settings and set 3 things, extent, snap, cell size all pointing to raster

Comment: @FelixIP I tried those settings with both 'Raster to Polygon' and 'Extract by Attributes', but still getting the same reduction in cell count as before.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to output to shapefiles and calculate area? Copy raster to old era grid first...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65632/discussion-between-ffinnm-and-felixip).